# Return the rows that are above average

Tags: sql, count, average

I'm trying to find the countries from which the number of orders is higher than the average. This is as far as I got. The problem is (see picture) that the count of orders for each country is off, as it should be different for everyone

```
  SELECT avg(NumberOrders) as avg, 
         Customers.Country, 
         NumberOrders
    FROM Customers,
          (SELECT COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS NumberOrders 
             FROM Customers JOIN 
                  Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
         GROUP BY Customers.Country) nested
GROUP BY Customers.Country
  HAVING NumberOrders > avg;
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbI8J.png)

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: I'm using db browser for sqlite.

Comment: the database is northwind

Comment: total average (over all countries) or country average?

Comment: total average, the average of the order count among all countries

Comment: what database?  if MSSQL 2008+ you can used windowed functions and a CTE.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: you can use window functions and CTEs in pretty much every modern DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DBMS supports *Windowed Aggregates* (almost all besides MySQL & Access):

```
select *
from
 (
   SELECT Customers.Country, 
      COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS NumberOrders,  -- count per country
      AVG(COUNT(Orders.OrderId)) OVER () AS avgOrders -- average count
   FROM Customers
   JOIN Orders 
     ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
   GROUP BY Customers.Country
 ) nested
WHERE NumberOrders > avgOrders
```

Edit:

For DBMSes not supporting *Windowed Aggregates* it's way more complicated:

```
SELECT Customers.Country, 
   COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS NumberOrders  -- count per country
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders 
  ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.Country
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderId) >
 ( select avg(NumberOrders)
   from
    (
      SELECT Customers.Country, 
         COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS NumberOrders  -- count per country
      FROM Customers
      JOIN Orders 
        ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
      GROUP BY Customers.Country
    ) AS dt
 )
```

If the DBMS supports *Common Table Expressions* this can be simplified:

```
with cte as
 (
   SELECT Customers.Country, 
      COUNT(Orders.OrderId) AS NumberOrders  -- count per country
   FROM Customers
   JOIN Orders 
     ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
   GROUP BY Customers.Country
 ) 
select *
from cte
WHERE NumberOrders >
 (
   select avg(NumberOrders) from cte
 )
```

Comment: You didn't used windowed.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the input! unfortunatly there seems to be a syntax error and I cannot quite figure out where

Comment: @Jako: Based on one of your comments you're using `sqlite`, which doesn't support `OVER`

Comment: @Jako: I added an solution for old DBMSes :-)

Comment: @dnoeth, thank you very much for your insights! I still don't get the any results :/

Comment: @Jako: *no results* due to an error message? There was an alias missing and the `HAVING` might fail, both are fixed. Should work now and return 7 countries ...